# How to include script from SQL sever?

Tags: javascript, c#

I have script string from SQL, this is my script from SQL:

(function (w, d, u) {
            var s = d.createElement('script'); s.async = true; s.src = u + '?' + (Date.now() / 60000 | 0);
            var h = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; h.parentNode.insertBefore(s, h);
        })(window, document, 'https://cdn.bitrix24.vn/b23267373/crm/site_button/loader_2_pqn2tk.js');

I want to include it in the client Website in  using C#. How to do that?

Comment: So you have stored the code in the SQL server and you need to run that code on web browser. What type of application you are developing? ASP.NET MVC? Blazor? or SPA using Angular or Vue?

Comment: Yes, I used ASP.NET MVC and Angular

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a page that queries the database based on a query string parameter and then echos the script content with the header "Content-Type: text/javascript".  So you access it like https://example.com/getScript.aspx?scriptId=123.
2. In your JavaScript, do something like this:

```js
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.src = "https://example.com/getScript.aspx?scriptId=123";
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
```

Comment: How to use C# for that? is there any other way? Thanks